# PHP Split and sort data in new array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, php-7.3

Restructuring PHP array data.
Testing the "data block 1" works fine and the data is correctly exploded in $newArray_1 and finally sorted in $newArray_2. I do not really use the explode but choosed to kept it in the code since it will be used later to extract the needed name of key within new arrays.

**Question:** Is it possible to use the same code base in order to solve with the same handling of "data block 2" ?

---

**My code:**

```
// Unsorted array -------------------------------------

$frontendData = [
  'datasheet' => [
    'Name_1_balance0'    => 1, // Data block 1
    'Name_1_balance2'    => 3, // Data block 1
    'Name_1_balance3'    => 4, // Data block 1
    'Name_1_balance1'    => 2, // Data block 1
    // 'Name_2_balance0'    => 5, // Data block 2
    // 'Name_2_balance2'    => 7, // Data block 2
    // 'Name_2_balance3'    => 8, // Data block 2
    // 'Name_2_balance1'    => 6, // Data block 2
  ]
];

ksort($frontendData['datasheet']);
print_r($frontendData);

// Explode array -------------------------------------

$newArray_1 = [];

foreach ( $frontendData as $mainKey => $elements )  {
    foreach ( $elements as $subKey => $value ){
        $newData = explode("_", $subKey);
        $newData[] = $value;
        $newArray_1[$mainKey][] = $newData;
    }
}

print_r($newArray_1);

// Restructure array -------------------------------------

$newArray_2['datasheet'] = ['Name_1'];


for ($i=0; $i <=3 ; $i++) {

  $newArray_2['datasheet'][1]['balance'][$i] =
    $newArray_1['datasheet'][$i][3];

}

print_r($newArray_2);
```

---

**Result (Processing "Data block 1"):**

```
Array
(
    [datasheet] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name_1
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [balance] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => 2
                            [2] => 3
                            [3] => 4
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**Wanted result (Processing "Data block 1" & "Data block 2"):**

```
Array
(
    [datasheet] => 
        Array
        (
            [0] => Name_1
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [balance] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => 2
                            [2] => 3
                            [3] => 4
                        )

                )

        ),
        Array
        (
            [0] => Name_2
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [balance] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 5
                            [1] => 6
                            [2] => 7
                            [3] => 8
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Why the extra level of array for `balance`?

Comment: @Nick In some occasions I will need to iterate with loops over the data and then it is easier to have key with index instead of key name.

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Comment: @Nick Actually both answers works fine. Difference is the amount of code and method used, also the result comes in different order, which does not matter since I might iterate over the data and then it is mostly important that the data is indexed, not the order of the data. I am not that familiar with "pregmatch" but it makes sense due to the reduced amount of needed code. Will study it a bit since I want to avoid to inject code snippets that I do not fully understand.

Comment: Good to hear. If you are concerned about the order of the data that my answer provides, you can always `ksort($frontendData['datasheet']);` before the loop.

Comment: See https://3v4l.org/GmgcG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over your `$frontendData` array, using `preg_match` to extract the name and balance number (thus avoiding the need to sort the array), and building a result array using those values indexed by the name. We then use `array_values` to re-index the array numerically and assign it to a `datasheet` key in the output:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($frontendData['datasheet'] as $key => $balance) {
    preg_match('/^(\w+)_balance(\d+)$/', $key, $match);
    $result[$match[1]][0] = $match[1];
    $result[$match[1]][1]['balance'][$match[2]] = $balance;
}
$result = array('datasheet' => array_values($result));
print_r($result);
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
Array
(
    [datasheet] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Name_1
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [balance] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1
                                    [2] => 3
                                    [3] => 4
                                    [1] => 2
                                )
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Name_2
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [balance] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 5
                                    [2] => 7
                                    [3] => 8
                                    [1] => 6
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/FNYfv)

Note that entries in the `balance` array occur in the same order as they are in the original `datasheet` array so indexes may not be in numeric order. If that is a concern (for example, if you wanted to iterate the values using `foreach` rather than a `for` loop over the indexes), you should sort `$frontendData['datasheet']` by its keys, using `uksort` with a callback of `strnatcmp` to ensure that `balance10` sorts after `balance2` to `balance9`:

```
uksort($frontendData['datasheet'], 'strnatcmp');
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/gVe5W)

Comment: Nice, superclean.  Please add the ksort advice to this answer.  Note, double-digit numbered keys will be mis-ordered by ksort if done before splitting the string into values.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
// Unsorted array -------------------------------------

$frontendData = [
  'datasheet' => [
    'Name_2_balance0'    => 5, // Data block 2
    'Name_1_balance0'    => 1, // Data block 1
    'Name_1_balance2'    => 3, // Data block 1
    'Name_1_balance3'    => 4, // Data block 1
    'Name_1_balance1'    => 2, // Data block 1
    'Name_2_balance2'    => 7, // Data block 2
    'Name_2_balance3'    => 8, // Data block 2
    'Name_2_balance1'    => 6, // Data block 2
  ]
];

ksort($frontendData['datasheet']);
// print_r($frontendData);

// Explode array -------------------------------------

$newArray_1 = array('datasheet'=>array());
$key='';
$i = 0;
foreach ( $frontendData['datasheet'] as $mainKey => $elements )  {
    $newData = explode("_", $mainKey);
    if(sizeof($newData)>=3){
        $newkey=$newData[0].'_'.$newData[1];
        if($newkey!=$key){
            $key=$newkey;
            array_push($newArray_1['datasheet'],array());
            array_push($newArray_1['datasheet'][$i], $newkey);
            array_push($newArray_1['datasheet'][$i], array());
            $k=array();
            array_push($k, $elements);
            $newArray_1['datasheet'][$i][1]=array('balance' => $k);
            $i++;

        }else{
            array_push($newArray_1['datasheet'][$i-1][1]['balance'], $elements);
        }

    }

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray_1);
echo "</pre>";
// Restructure array -------------------------------------

//$newArray_2['datasheet'] = ['Name_1'];

?>
```